# Error while parsing xml file in python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

This is the xml file I am trying to parse. This file does not have a root tag.

```
<data txt="some0" txt1 = "some1" txt2 = "some2" >
     <data2>
            < bank = "SBI" bank2 = "SBI2" >
     <data2>
     <data3>
            <branch = "bang1" branch = bang"2" >
     <data3>
<data>
```

My script contains below lines. The below can be used to get the specific data after parsing it.

```
data = re.findall("<data txt=.*?</data>", re.DOTALL)
tree = ElementTree.fromstringlist(data)
```

I am unabale to parse this file because its not having root tag. please help me how to parse if the file is having no tag ??

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression in the first place? Just parse the *whole* document, leave the selection to ElementTree.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : The xml does not have root tag, hence i am not able to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment already, you can just parse the whole thing. If the missing root element is the problem, you can grab the contents of the file as a string and then add an arbitrary root tag at the beginning and the end.

```
stringdata = "<myroot>%s</myroot>" % stringdata
```

and then parse the string.

**EDIT:**

In response to comment.

If you have one string, you'll want fromstring, but you'll almost certainly get the same error. Something else is going on. Try this ...

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
stringdata = "<myroot>%s</myroot>" % stringdata
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(stringdata)
```

Then get what you need from tree.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : i got the xml data in one variable now. i tried to parse it using above my two line script, but its throwing an error "'module' object has no attribute 'fromstringlist'" ? can you help me to parse this data ?